# Py3 Проблема с кодировкой pdf документов из txt-файла

Tags: python, парсер, печать

При печати в pdf-файл из txt (кодировка utf-8) происходит следующее
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]
 txt2pdf.py:

```
from reportlab.platypus import SimpleDocTemplate, Paragraph
from reportlab.lib.styles import getSampleStyleSheet
from reportlab.lib.units import inch
from reportlab.lib.pagesizes import letter


def txt2pdf(path):
    styles = getSampleStyleSheet()
    styleN = styles['Normal']
    story = []

    pdf_name = 'pdf.pdf'
    doc = SimpleDocTemplate(
        pdf_name,
        pagesize=letter,
        bottomMargin=.4 * inch,
        topMargin=.6 * inch,
        rightMargin=.8 * inch,
        leftMargin=.8 * inch)
    try:
        txt_file = open(path, 'r')
    except:
        print('0')
    text_content = txt_file.read()

    P = Paragraph(text_content, styleN)
    story.append(P)
    doc.build(story)
```

Answer (score 0):

Нужно зарегистрировал кириллический шрифт

```
from reportlab.pdfbase import pdfmetrics

pdfmetrics.registerFont(TTFont('DejaVuSans', 'DejaVuSans.ttf', 'utf-8'))
```

И использовать его при создании документа

```
body_style = ParagraphStyle('Body', fontName="DejaVuSans", fontSize=10)
p = Paragraph(text_content , body_style)
```